# Upgrading the selenium-java version from 4.4.0 to 4.8.2 is causing a WebDriverManagerException error creating WebDriver object for Chrome

Tags: macos, maven, selenium-webdriver

Brief: I ran into issues with the Chrome browser due to the upgrade [v-111.x], so when the update on selenium-java 4.8.2/4.8.3 were available. I updated the .POM to the 4.8.2 version upon which which I am seeing following error :

```
*io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.instantiateDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1775)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.create(WebDriverManager.java:425)
    at base.TestBase.OpenSendSteps(TestBase.java:37)
    at testCases.UserSignupTest.setUp(UserSignupTest.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createLocalWebDriver(WebDriverCreator.java:64)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.createLocalWebDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1949)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.instantiateDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1764)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.io.File findDefaultExecutable()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    ... 43 more


POM : 

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
-    <version>4.4.0</version>
+    <version>4.8.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

System details:

MacBook Pro - 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
System Version: macOS 13.0 (22A380)
Chrome version - Version 111.0.5563.146
ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64

I have tried to downgraded the browser version and chrome driver versions and my tests run fine, it is after the upgrade that the tests are failing

Comment: Have you got any work around? I am using IOSDriver and failing   after updating Chrome to 111.* and selenium-java to 4.8.2/4.8.3 with an error "ChromeDriverServiceBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.io.File findDefaultExecutable()"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm a bit late to the party, but since Chrome v111 the webdriver argument `--remote-allow-origins=*` is required.

for reference: https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/xL5-13_qGaA